# Understanding the bytes in a pcl2 message

Tags: python, pcl, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using python in order to publish pointclouds. Prior to this I'd like to run some segmentation using [python-pcl](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl) and colorize each cluster. Unfortunately, the only function that creates a pcl message from a numpy array does so without considering color (only x, y, z).

```
pcl2.create_cloud_xyz32(header, nx3_numpy_array)
```

Therefore, I want to create a ros message then tweak it manually to change the color of each point. Here is an example message:

```
header: 
  seq: 1535
  stamp: 
    secs: 1524593497
    nsecs: 322609179
  frame_id: "gripper_depth_camera_rgb_optical_frame"
height: 480
width: 640
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "rgb"
    offset: 16
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 32
row_step: 20480
data: [0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

It is easy to understand why x, y and z require 4 bytes each (float 32)

But why does rgb come at 16 and not 12? following the logic, z also needs 4 bytes, and the next free spot is at an offset of 12 and not 16.

Also why does rgb need 16 bytes? (point_step is 32 so one point requires 32 bytes from which 16 are for rgb). The color values themselves need only one byte each so this is confusing. Also, if we say the are float32 values, 16 bytes means 4 values, is the fourth value the transparency (RGBA?)

Here is an example from an XYZ only pointcloud where my understanding fits:

```
header: 
  seq: 5
  stamp: 
    secs: 1524583199
    nsecs: 372246980
  frame_id: "gripper_depth_camera_rgb_optical_frame"
height: 1
width: 231
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 12
row_step: 2772
data: [125, 207, 94, 190, 220, 24, 98, 190, 254, 67, 60, 63, 69, 231, 92, 190, 6
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289576/understanding-the-bytes-in-a-pcl2-message/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your datatype for rgb is wrong, it should be like this- the 7 is a 32 bit floating point type, this 6 is a 32 bit unsigned int:

```
  ...
  - 
    name: "rgb"
    offset: 12
    datatype: 6
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 16
...
```

You don't need to do it manually though, sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 create_cloud will help out (though the packing of the rgb bytes maybe could be better?):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PointCloud2 color cube
import rospy
import struct

from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField
from std_msgs.msg import Header


rospy.init_node("create_cloud_xyzrgb")
pub = rospy.Publisher("point_cloud2", PointCloud2, queue_size=2)

points = []
lim = 8
for i in range(lim):
    for j in range(lim):
        for k in range(lim):
            x = float(i) / lim
            y = float(j) / lim
            z = float(k) / lim
            pt = [x, y, z, 0]
            r = int(x * 255.0)
            g = int(y * 255.0)
            b = int(z * 255.0)
            a = 255
            print r, g, b, a
            rgb = struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('BBBB', b, g, r, a))[0]
            print hex(rgb)
            pt[3] = rgb
            points.append(pt)

fields = [PointField('x', 0, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('y', 4, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('z', 8, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
          PointField('rgb', 12, PointField.UINT32, 1),
          # PointField('rgba', 12, PointField.UINT32, 1),
          ]

header = Header()
header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
header.frame_id = "map"
pc2 = point_cloud2.create_cloud(header, fields, points)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    pc2.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    pub.publish(pc2)
    rospy.sleep(1.0)
```

The alpha value goes along for the ride for free above, unless rgba is used, and then rviz will pay attention to it and render the transparency.

All the valid fields and types are here: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview
The above could be added to point_cloud2.py, but you can see from the numerous fields that the number of convenience functions that anyone might want is very large.  It would be useful to have a few more examples available.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2018-04-25**:
Thanks !! that is exactly what I needed. The first message example is from a "depth_registered" topic from the openni driver so maybe there is more to it than just simple rgb.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-04-25**:
Does rviz show the colors in that `depth_registered` topic properly?